# how to setup pyspark with zeppelin on windows 10

Tags: apache-spark, apache-zeppelin

I have had difficulties installing Zeppelin 0.7.2

Using the Zeppelin version 0.7.2 of spark that comes with it, I can run spark code, but I am unable to run %pyspark code even after modifying python environment variables to point to where python is installed (python was installed using anaconda).

%python code works fine.

If anyone can help resolve this issue I would be grateful. (The odd thing is I have done the same installation on another windows 10 laptop and pyspark does execute.)

The error I get is that: pyspark is not responding

Comment: Hi, what about trying dockerized zeppelin 0.7.2? `docker run -p 8080:8080 --rm -v $PWD/logs:/logs -v $PWD/notebook:/notebook -e ZEPPELIN_LOG_DIR='/logs' -e ZEPPELIN_NOTEBOOK_DIR='/notebook' --name zeppelin apache/zeppelin:0.7.2`